# How to carry over ending balance from one sheet to beginning balance of newly created sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to write a code that will carry over the ending balance of each product from one sheet to the beginning balance cell of the newly created sheet.
The code works for the first product but then as it offsets columns, the ending balance isnt being carried over, only the beginning balance is. The following is my vba code. The ending balances of each product are all positioned in row 39 but are offseted by 4 columns. beginning balance is row 7 and same offset (4). the loop exists because im using this vba code for many different workbooks and the number of products differ for each workbook.

> Sub newsheet()
>   'Function allows the user to copy paste the new sheet,
>   'all contents in columns payments and advances of each product are cleared but the formating is kept the same.

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
Range("C8:D38,H8:I38,M8:N38,R8:S38,W8:X38,AB8:AC38,AG8:AH38,AL8:AM38," & _
"AQ8:AR38 , AV8:AW38 , BA8:BB38 , BF8:BG38 , BK8:BL38 , BP8:BQ38 , BU8:BV38 , BZ8:CA38," & _
"CE8: CF38 , CJ8: CK38 , CO8: CP38 , CT8: CU38 , CY8: CZ38 , DD8: DE38 ").ClearContents

' Setting up new variables for the following procedure
' it will allow the user to copy paste ending balance of old sheet to beginning balance of the new sheet
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set wks = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Previous
Set rng = wks.Range("E39")
Set rng2 = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E7")

Do While Not IsEmpty(rng)
' loops through the copied sheets facilities.
    rng.Copy
    rng2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 4)
    Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(0, 4)
Loop 'Loops back through the previous sheet until it doesnt find any product anymore.
```

End Sub

Comment: why not just use a formula? sumifs or index/aggregate shouls be appropriate.

Comment: i cant because the macro creates a new sheet. and i want the ending balance cell value carried forward to the beginning balance cell.

Comment: When you create a new worksheet at the end of the worksheet queue, just write the formula referencing the previous worksheet'send balanance into it.

Comment: im not creating a worksheet manually, its in the vba code... maybe im not understanding your solution sorry :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your problem, anyway, I would try this:

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
Range("C8:D38,H8:I38,M8:N38,R8:S38,W8:X38,AB8:AC38,AG8:AH38,AL8:AM38," & _
"AQ8:AR38 , AV8:AW38 , BA8:BB38 , BF8:BG38 , BK8:BL38 , BP8:BQ38 , BU8:BV38 , BZ8:CA38," & _
"CE8: CF38 , CJ8: CK38 , CO8: CP38 , CT8: CU38 , CY8: CZ38 , DD8: DE38 ").ClearContents

' Setting up new variables for the following procedure
' it will allow the user to copy paste ending balance of old sheet to beginning balance of the new sheet
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set wks = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Previous
Set rng = wks.Range("E39")
Set rng2 = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E7")

Do While Not IsEmpty(rng)
' loops through the copied sheets facilities.

    rng2.Value2 = rng.Value2

    Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 4)
    Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(0, 4)
Loop 'Loops back through the previous sheet until it doesnt find any product anymore.
```

Otherwise show image of a worksheet with same exemplary data, pls.

Comment: actually i just found the mistake... offset 5, it should have been . silly.. thank you anyways